# Few ids in urlspattern

Tags: django, rest, url

I am making a API with REST Framework.

I can't find out how to create an urlspattern that got 2 id's from main model and primary model.

**Models**:

```
class Diary(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)


class DiaryRecord(models.Model):
    diaryID = models.ForeignKey(Diary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
```

**Sample**:

```
path('api/diary/<int:firstID>/record-update/<int:secondID>/', views.defName) #firstId is id of Diary(Main model). Second id is DiaryRecord id.
```

So i need to show a records, that belong to Diary.

Comment: You are using django rest framework?

Comment: You don't need the `firstID` in that url per se. Your `DiaryRecord` has a foreign key to `Diary` so you can get that object from the `DiaryRecord` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by coding this:

```
def recordDetail(request, pk, diaryID):
    get_objects = DiaryRecord.objects.filter(diaryID=diaryID)
    queryset = get_objects.get(id=pk)

    serializer = RecordSerializer(queryset)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Thank you everyone.